# Right syntax of SQL query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables in SQL DB:

```
SUBJECT(idSUB,nameSUB);
TOPIC(idTOP,nameTOP,idSUB);
```

All I want is:

```
+ select COUNT(*) from TOPIC as numTOPIC group by idSUB--> as a Temp table
+ then join 2 table Temp and SUBJECT --> a new table(idSUB,nameSUB,numTOPIC)
```

But I've tried many time but I really dont know the exactly syntax of this SQL query.
Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to join `subject` with `topic`.

```
SELECT  a.idsub, a.namesub,
        COUNT(b.idsub) numTOPIC 
FROM    subject a
        LEFT JOIN topic b
            ON a.idsub = b.idsub
GROUP   BY a.idsub, a.namesub
```